# How to set title for text_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I know that is something simple, but I'm stuck. 
I have a several forms in my rails3 app to which I need to add tooltips, by using the [tipsy](https://github.com/vanntastic/tipsy). The text in tooltips should be determined in title\original-title, but I just can't figure it out, how to set it for text_field.

```
<%= f.text_field :what %>
```

gives me

```
<input id="name_which" name="name[which]" size="30" type="text">
```

and I just can't figure it out, where to put the title text.

For example, this one in html works fine

```
<input type="text" name="tooltipform" title="Tooltip text">
```

In application.js it is determined by

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#form-example [title]').tipsy({trigger: 'focus', gravity: 'w'});
```

});

I know that is something basic and I'm ashamed of my self. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite simple, pass it as an option:

<%= f.text_field :what, :title => "Tooltip text %>

Other html attributes can also be set as this, such as :class, :id, etc.

Comment: Phhh, I was so close... Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try with:

```
<%= f.text_field :what, :title => 'whatever' %>
```