# Change number field message in rails 5

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <%= form.number_field :program_registration_cost, required: true, id: 'program_registration_cost', class: "form-control", step: "any" %>
</div>
```

I am using number_field for program registration cost and it shows a default message Please enter a number when I hover over it. I want to change this message.

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
 <%= form.number_field :program_registration_cost, required: true, id: 'program_registration_cost', class: "form-control", step: "any" oninvalid: "this.setCustomValidity('Please don't put $ in front of amount')" oninput: "setCustomValidity('')" %>
</div>
```

This is what I tried but it is not working. Please help me how can I achieve this.

[image]

Comment: You may be able to find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984028/how-to-set-title-for-text-field). It's a different question, but the answer should be the same (add a `title` attribute).

Comment: @thesecretmaster thankyou. I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
 <%= form.number_field :program_registration_cost,:title => "Only enter numbers - do not use a $ sign.", required: true, id: 'program_registration_cost', class: "form-control", step: "any" %>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide some description as to why your answer meets the needs of the original poster. This helps the original poster as well as anyone who finds this answer.